# Why does hyphsubst not work with LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

Consider the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine with `pdflatex` but not with `lualatex`. Why is there an error when using the latest hyphenation patterns? Can I make them work with `lualatex`?

---

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011061410 (rev 4277) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./BabelTest.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8l-luatex-1.5> and hyphenation patterns for engl
ish, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hyphsubst.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty))
(./scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
! LuaTeX error ...11/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:60: luat
ex-hyphen: \language0 should be dumped in the format
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...11/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:22: in function 'err'
    ...11/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:60: in function 'loadl
anguage'
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
\bbl@patterns ...pestring {#1}", \the \language )}
                                                  \fi \fi \fi 
l.131 \main@language{english}
```

Comment: No errors here, what is the version of Babel printed in the top of your log? Here I've `LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8l-luatex-1.5>`, I suspect earlier versions to cause an error (recently the issue with Babel aliases was fixed).

Comment: I am sorry, I put in the wrong documentclass. It now turns out it just does not work with the KOMA Script classes. Can you compile the above code as well? See also the error message.

Comment: Still no error here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the last question of the OP "Can I make them work with lualatex?":

Patterns from package dehyph-exptl are already included in package hyph-utf8 and those patterns are activated for UTF-8 aware TeX engines, e.g., LuaTeX and XeTeX.  Because German patterns for TeX and pdfTeX are frozen, package hyph-utf8 contains conventional German patterns, too, but activates those only for said 8 bit TeX engines.

That is, when using LuaLaTeX you don't need to care about packages dehyph-exptl and hyph-subst at all.  This example

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\begin{document}
\showhyphens{modernste}
\end{document}
```

when compiled with LaTeX and LuaLaTeX should show the following results:

```
             german           ngerman

LaTeX        mo-d-ern-ste     mo-d-erns-te
LuaLaTeX     mo-dern-ste      mo-derns-te
```

You can find out what version of experimental German patterns are shipped with package hyph-utf8 (usually the latest) by typing

```sh
$head `kpsewhich hyph-de-1901.lic.txt`
```

on the shell.  Windows users type

```sh
>for /F "usebackq" %f in (`kpsewhich hyph-de-1901.lic.txt`) do more "%f"
```

on the command-line.  Note the backquotes surrounding the `kpsewhich` calls!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 6):

I've got no error when compiling with LuaTeX, but `hyphsubst` doesn't seem to work with LuaTeX. You can verify by running the following document with LuaTeX:

```
\RequirePackage[german=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\begin{document}
\showhyphens{Meister}
\end{document}
```

It should report `Meis-ter` but reports `Mei-ster`. With `luatex -recorder test.tex` you can look into the generated `.fls` file and see that only the file `hyph-de-1901.pat.txt` gets loaded.

Comment: No wonder, loading hyphenation patterns is completely different under lualatex.

Comment: @KhaledHosny And why shouldn't hyphsubst be able to switch between different backends as it does now with LaTeX and TeX? I don't see a technical difficulty.

Comment: I’ve no idea how `hyphsubst` works, but without it’s author explicitly adding support for LuaTeX, it is unlikely to work out of box. We have LuaTeX specific version of Babel’s `hyphen.cfg` to handle loading patterns in a LuaTeX specific way.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach I've added some code; can you point to a word that's hyphenated differently with `ngerman` and `ngerman-x-latest`?

Comment: @egreg ab-fal-lauf-be-rei-tung (ngerman) and ab-fall-auf-be-rei-tung (latest)

Comment: @PatrickGundlach As I suspected, the language is changed, but no hyphenation patterns are available for the new one. Maybe Khaled can shed some light.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach There's something strange: the word is hyphenated as `ab-fall-auf-be-rei-tung` with LuaLaTeX and as `ab-fal-lauf-be-rei-tung` with LaTeX. Both with option `ngerman` to `babel`.

Comment: @egreg strange indeed. I can confirm that but I have no explanation so far

Comment: LuaLaTeX chooses automatically the new(est) hyphenation pattern.

„Mit den nicht unterstützten TEX-Programmen können experimentelle Trennmuster dennoch verwendet werden, da das Paket hyph-utf8 ebenfalls Muster dieses Projekts enthält. Werden die UTF-8-fähigen Programme XeTEX und LuaTEX oder pTEX
5 verwendet, so werden jene Muster standardmäßig aktiviert.
Die Trennmuster dieses Pakets sollten dann nicht verwendet werden.“

http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/hyphenation/dehyph-exptl/dehyph-exptl.pdf#site=4

Answer (score 5):

`hyphsubst` simply changes the number associated to the control sequence that LaTeX uses when choosing a language.

For instance `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` executes, among other things, `\language\l@ngerman` and `\l@ngerman` is defined at format creation to be the number `"1E` (on my machine, it can vary according to the `language.dat` file).

The number corresponding to `ngerman-x-latest` is (on my machine) `"4`.

When one says

```
\RequirePackage[german=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
```

the basic action is to change the meaning of `\l@ngerman` into `"4`; more precisely, the action is

```
\chardef\l@ngerman=\csname l@ngerman-x-latest\endcsname
```

Of course, if the languages are not preloaded, as it happens with LuaLaTeX, this can't work (precautions are taken in the package so as a correct assignment is performed even if the meaning of `\csname l@ngerman-x-latest\endcsname` was `\relax`). That's why we end with the patterns for English, I guess.

### A possible step towards a solution

Apparently, LuaLaTeX knows about the correct numbers, so what's needed is to force loading the correct language. A test:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% print the numbers
\typeout{ngerman: \number\csname l@ngerman\endcsname}
\typeout{ngerman-x-latest: \number\csname l@ngerman-x-latest\endcsname}

\usepackage{hyphsubst}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\typeout{Current language: \number\language}

\HyphSubstLet{ngerman}{ngerman-x-latest}

\typeout{Current language: \number\language}

\end{document}
```

The relevant part of the log file shows

```
ngerman: 30
ngerman-x-latest: 4
[...]
Current language: 30
Current language: 4
```

so the value of `\language` seems to be correctly set. However the `.fls` file reports only

```
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-de-1996.pat.txt
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-de-1996.pat.txt
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-de-1996.hyp.txt
```

which seems to mean that the hyphenation patterns for `ngerman-x-latest` are not loaded.

I've tried to add something like

```
%% Load the new language
\setbox0=\vbox{
  \everypar{}\begin{hyphenrules}{ngerman-x-latest}abc\end{hyphenrules}
}
```

in the preamble or in the document, in order to see if the patterns are loaded, but this doesn't seem so.

Comment: Check http://tug.org/svn/texhyphen/trunk/hyph-utf8/doc/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.pdf?view=co for how patterns are loaded with lualatex.

Comment: @KhaledHosny The macro responsible for it seems to be `\bbl@patterns`, which *is* called with `ngerman-x-latest`, but doesn't seem to load the patterns. :(